# pandas idxmax return all columns with maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
column_1    column_2
2           3
6           4
5           5
.
.
.
```

I would like to return for each row of the above dataframe the name(s) of the column(s) which have the maximum value in that row; for example for the first row I want to return 'column_2', and for the third row it will return both column names since they both have the same value.

I have tried to achieve it by using Pandas's idxmax function; but this function returns only the first occurrence and ignores the rest of the possibilities; like in the example of the third row above, idxmax returns only 'column_1' instead of ['column_1', 'column_2'].

Any idea how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each row, you can check if the entry is equal to the maximum of that row; this will form a boolean frame. Then you can `dot` product it with the column names to choose those columns' names that gave `True` for the rows:

```
is_max = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
result = is_max.dot(df.columns + " ")
```

where `axis=1` of `max` says take the maximum of each row and `axis=0` of `eq` says align the argument (i.e., `df.max(axis=1)`) to compare row-wise i.e., broadcast so),

to get

```
>>> is_max

   column_1  column_2
0     False      True
1      True     False
2      True      True

>>> result

0             column_2
1             column_1
2    column_1 column_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from numpy dot, we can use numpy broadcasting

```py
mask = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
df['max'] = ((df.columns * mask)[mask]
             .agg(lambda row: list(row.dropna()), axis=1))
```

```
print(df)

   column_1  column_2                   max
0         2         3            [column_2]
1         6         4            [column_1]
2         5         5  [column_1, column_2]
```